# Getting multiple url? Is this possible in Selenium

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have list of urls for which I want to write a small Smoke test.

Just load the urls and assert the title to make sure they are alive. Is this possible to do?    class identity(unittest.TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):

self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = self.driver
self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

@data('https://idsvr-test.sc.com/account/signin','https://launchpad-test.sc.com/#&ui-      state=dialog','https://ambassador-test.sc.com/')  
def test_login_identity(self,url):  

self.driver.get("https://idsvr-test.sc.com/account/signin")
self.assertIn("Username / Password Sign In", self.driver.title)
elemU = self.driver.find_element_by_name("UserName").send_keys(User)
elemP = self.driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(sDecryptPassword)
self.driver.find_element_by_id("login").click()
try:

  self.assertEqual("MyTitle", self.driver.title)
  print("I asserted the Title")

except Exception as e:
  print(e)

try:
  self.driver.get("https://launchpad-test.sc.com/#&ui-state=dialog") 
  self.assertIn("Launch Pad",self.driver.title)
  ltitle = self.driver.title
  print( "New page" + ltitle)


except Exception as e:
 print(e)


 try:

  self.driver.get("https://ambassador-test.sc.com/")  
  self.assertIn("SC: Ambassador",self.driver.title)
  atitle = self.driver.title
  print(atitle)
 except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
   unittest.main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really looks like a data-driven test. In this case, [`ddt`](http://ddt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package can help to make it easy:

> DDT (Data-Driven Tests) allows you to multiply one test case by
>   running it with different test data, and make it appear as multiple
>   test cases.

```
from ddt import ddt, data

@ddt
class identity(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

    @data('url1', 'url2', 'url3')
    def test_login_identity(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        # ...
```

Applying `@ddt` and `@data` decorators would basically auto-generate a test method for every url passed inside the `@data`. In this example, you would have 3 test methods being executed by the `unittest` runner.

Comment: Thank you so much... Now it is running but it is running the first 2 tests only 3 times... The 3rd "get.url" didn't work. Any idea  Appreciate your help

Comment: @user2744620 you are welcome, first two steps, could you please describe in more details what is happening and what you want to happen? Thank you.

Comment: This is what is happening 1.It gets the first URL and Login happens and asserts the Title. 2. It gets the Second Url and asserts the tilte. 3. These 2 repeats for about 3 times and I have 3 different opened sessions. What I want is, 1. Login using the very first Url. 2. Access 2nd url and assert the page 3. Access/get 3rd Url and assert the page. and so on... I have about 5 urls that I want to validate this. The first login should remember the session opened and allow remaining urls to login without any uname/password.

Comment: @user2744620 gotcha, ddt still is smth that you can use. Can you post the complete code you have (edit the question and post it there please)?

Comment: Just edited my initial post and posted the code there. Appreciate your time. Thanks.